# How to get control over DepthFirstScan?

Tags: programming, graphs-and-networks

Is there a way to **conditionally** take control the flow during a depth-first scan against a **TreeGraph**?

I have a tree graph whose nodes are constructed as object, and there's a method `isTrue[para_]` for each node.

```
isValid[desc] = "Check whether input is valid";
isValid[isTrue, para_] := Module[{result},
    result = SyntaxQ[para];
    Return[result];
];

isNumber[desc] = "Check whether input is a number";
isNumber[isTrue, para_] := Module[{result},
    result = NumberQ[ToExpression[para]];
    Return[result];
];

isInteger[desc] = "Check whether input is an integer";
isInteger[isTrue, para_] := Module[{result},
    result = IntegerQ[ToExpression[para]];
    Return[result];
];

isFraction[desc] = "Check whether input is a fraction";
isFraction[isTrue, para_] := Module[{result},
    result = !IntegerQ[ToExpression[para]];
    Return[result];
]; 

tree = 
  TreeGraph[{isValid, isNumber, isInteger, isFraction}, 
    {isValid -> isNumber, isNumber -> isInteger, isNumber -> isFraction},
    VertexLabels->"Name"];
```

Here is the tree image of the code, The root is `isValid`.

[image: The structure of tree]

If my input is "3.5", I expect the depth-scan flow should be `isValid -> isNumber -> isFraction` because the `isInteger` gives `False`.

I tried `Abort[]` like (as well as `Return[]`):

```
DepthFirstScan[tree, isValid, 
 "DiscoverVertex" -> (If[#[isTrue, "3.5"], Print[#], Abort[]]&)];
```

But this broke the whole scan flow. What I want is: when the node gives `False`, it and its child-nodes should be skipped, but the scan should continue scanning the remaining nodes.

Comment: Some advice on coding. `isValid` can be reduced to `isValid[isTrue, para_] := SyntaxQ[para]`. Similar reductions can be made to your other functions.

Comment: @m_goldberg thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DepthFirstScan` as well as `BreadthFirstScan` has no such functionality. However, you can construct a temporary graph without unwanted edges

```
n = 8;
SeedRandom[0];
g = GridGraph[{n, n}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
  VertexStyle -> Thread[Range[n^2] -> RandomChoice[{3, 1} -> {White, Black}, n^2]]]
```

[image]

Here invalid vertices marked by black. Let's delete all corresponding edges

```
g2 = EdgeDelete[g, DirectedEdge[_, n_] /; PropertyValue[{g, n}, VertexStyle] == Black];

visited = Reap[DepthFirstScan[g2, 1, {"DiscoverVertex" -> (Sow[#] &)}]][[2, 1]];

HighlightGraph[g, visited]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. You pointed me a correct way to do this.